# Docusign - How to get list of user using filter option in REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

I can filter out `userStatus=closed` in the admin console and I like to do that in REST API to get the users list. Is there any API is available for "get list users with filter parameter"?

Comment: Please share what you have tried in SO after exploring API Documentation etc, SO is normally used to post your code queries and people will help you in fixing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Per [DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Users/Users/list/), you need to use below call

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/users?status=closed
```

There are more filter parameters explained in the documentation